# How to use findstr to search multiple files

Tags: windows, command-prompt

When I use findstr on a single file, like this:

```
findstr "import" filename.py
```

it returns a number of matches.  But when I extend it to cover the current folder and sub-folders:

```
findstr /S "import" .
```

it doesn't find any matches.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

OK i've figured it out.  The /S option indicates searching current directory and all sub-directories, but I still need to specify a filename pattern.

This indicates all files:

```
findstr /S "import" *
```